# trying to foreach my database info without success

Tags: c#, php, xamarin, mysqli, xamarin.forms

I work with localhost as my backend and it looks something like this:

[image]

I get it via a httprequest like this in my class:

```
static public async Task<JArray> getOurMainInfo()
    {
        var httpClientRequest = new HttpClient ();

        var result = await httpClientRequest.GetAsync ("http://localhost/GetMyLocal.php");

        var resultString = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ();
        var jsonResult = JArray.Parse (resultString);

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine (jsonResult); //I get all the results here in my log.

        return jsonResult;

    }
```

A public class that I created:

```
public class Contact
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Number { get; set; }
}
```

And when I try to loop it and get the info out the code looks like this:

```
var createResult = await phpApi.getOurMainInfo ();

        foreach (var currentItem in createResult) {

            ourList.Add (new Contact () 
                { 
                    ID = currentItem ["ID"].ToString (), 
                    Name = currentItem ["Name"].ToString (), 
                    Number = currentItem ["Number"].ToString ()
                });
        };
```

And in my xaml to get the for example the names out:

```
<Label Text = "{Binding Name}"/>
```

I get no error but no result either.
If I however try to write out this in the log:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine (jsonResult["Name"]);
```

I get this error:

> Accessed JArray values with invalid key value: "Name". Int32 array index expected.`

Comment: in case of running the app on your phone, *localhost* is your phone. And I guess, the server doesn't run on your phone, right?

Comment: But your phone sends the request. Or are you running the app on your computer?

Comment: running the app on my computer yes

Comment: when I try this in the log: "System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine (jsonResult["Name"]);" i get this error: "Accessed JArray values with invalid key value: "Name". Int32 array index expected."

Comment: maybe you can use JObject instead of JArray. It is just a hunch.

Comment: If i use a JObject i get this error: "Error reading JObject from JsonReader. Current JsonReader item is not an object: StartArray. Path '', line 1, position 1."

Comment: Could you please post the complete json output as it comes in the response **as text**?

Comment: I solved the JArray problem but as I am lazy and used to work with JObjects I want that instead. (I created a new thread by the way with that).